# File execution after IWR download with IEX

Tags: windows, download, invoke-command, invoke-webrequest

I want to download a file from server and execute it, with single line command. I found this sollution `iwr site.com/file.exe -OutFile file.exe; file.exe`, but I don't like it. I'm looking for solution without storing downloaded file to disk. Also this needs to be done on windows machine without additional utilities installed.

It is somehow possible to use a pipe? Like this? `iwr site.com/file.exe | iex`

Answer (score 0):

I came with this solution (on windows machine) `curl -LOJ site.com/file.exe; ./file.exe` where `-L` is used for redirect.